# Como revelar itens ao chegar em determinado scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Eu gostaria de saber como se faz o efeito de revelar itens quando o scroll da página chega até o elemento, exemplo desse site: http://www.metodistapirassununga.org/

O efeito está nos blocos com imagens, que aparecem conforme vai abaixando o scroll.

Comment: galera, eu descobri como fazer, basta ter o scrollreveal.js que é um framework, pra nao ter que explicar detalhadamente, basta procurar por scrollreveal que ja acha bastante informações (em ingles). Pra quem quer o local em que entendi melhor esta aqui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePgnR4gHIi4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sem usar *plugins*, exceto o bom jQuery, o script abaixo faz efeito igual. Basta adicionar a classe `.mostar` às `divs` que deseja o efeito. Fiz uma animação simples de `fade in` mas pode ser adaptado para outro efeito que desejar:

```js
$(window).on("load scroll", function(){
 $(".mostrar").each(function(){
  var el = $(this);
  var eleHeight = el.outerHeight(); // altura da div
  var eleTopo = el.offset().top; // distancia da div ao topo do documento
  var scrlTopo = $(window).scrollTop(); // quanto foi rolada a janela
  var distance = eleTopo-scrlTopo; // distancia da div ao topo da janela
  var altJanela = window.innerHeight; // altura da janela
  if(distance <= altJanela-(eleHeight/2)) {
   el.animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 400);
  }
 });
});
```

```css
div{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background: red;
 float: left;
}
.mostrar{
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mostrar">
 div 1
</div>
<div class="mostrar">
 div 2
</div>
<div class="mostrar">
 div 3
</div>
<div class="mostrar">
 div 4
</div>
<div class="mostrar">
 div 5
</div>
```