# Como ativar plugin animate.css a partir do scroll?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Bom dia

Comecei a usar o plugin do animate.css e está funcionando a animação. No entanto eu queria que ela ativasse quando o scroll chegasse no elemento. O efeito está ocorrendo já quando a página carrega e o usuário acaba não vendo ele nos elementos mais pra baixo. Como faço?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ativar animação do desenho SVG ao chegar na div dele?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258074/como-ativar-anima%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-desenho-svg-ao-chegar-na-div-dele)

Comment: Além da possível duplicata acima, essa pergunta possui soluções nas perguntas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259659/8063 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252350/8063